# How to create a custom ReusableDbContext

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Three class:

- CustomDbContext
- ReusableContext
- DbContext

Relation:

- ReusableContext : DbContext
- CustomDbContext : ReusableContext

Code:

```
public class ReusableDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ReusableDbContext() 
        : base("name = myConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer＜ReusableDbContext＞(new 
MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion＜ReusableDbContext, ReusableMigrationsConfiguration＞());
    }

    public DbSet＜ReusableTable＞ ReusableTables{ get; set; }
}

public class ReusableMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration＜ReusableDbContext＞
{
    public ReusableMigrationsConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ReusableDbContext context)
    {
        //ReusableMigrationsConfiguration Seed Logic here
        // this Seed method is never called  -----------  The Problem here!
    }
}
```

then i try to Reuse the ReusableContext like this:

```
public class CustomDbContext : ReusableDbContext
{
    public CustomDbContext() 
        : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer＜CustomDbContext＞(new 
MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion＜CustomDbContext, CustomMigrationsConfiguration＞());
    }

    public DbSet＜CustomTable＞ CustomTables{ get; set; }
}

public class CustomMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration＜CustomDbContext＞
{
    public CustomMigrationsConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(CustomDbContext context)
    {
        //CustomMigrationsConfiguration Seed Logic
        // this Seed method is called, no problem here
    }
}
```

after running the project:

- ReusableTable and CustomTable are created
- Seed Method of CustomMigrationsConfiguration is called and OK
- BUT, Seed Method of ReusableMigrationsConfiguration is NOT called -------- What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, here is the solution.

Class:

- CustomDbContext, CustomMigrationsConfiguration
- ReusableContext, ReusableMigrationsConfiguration＜TContext＞
- DbContext

Relation:

- ReusableContext : DbContext
- ReusableMigrationsConfiguration＜TContext＞ : DbMigrationsConfiguration＜TContext＞
      where TContext : ReusableContext
- CustomDbContext : ReusableContext
- CustomMigrationsConfiguration : ReusableMigrationsConfiguration＜CustomDbContext＞

Code:

```
public class ReusableDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ReusableDbContext() 
        : base("name = myConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer＜ReusableDbContext＞(new 
MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion＜ReusableDbContext, ReusableMigrationsConfiguration＞());
    }

    public DbSet＜ReusableTable＞ ReusableTables{ get; set; }
}

public class ReusableMigrationsConfiguration＜TContext＞ : DbMigrationsConfiguration＜TContext＞ where TContext : ReusableDbContext
{
    public ReusableMigrationsConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(TContext context)
    {
        //ReusableMigrationsConfiguration Seed Logic here
        // is called and OK now.
    }
}
```

Now we can Reuse the ReusableContext like this:

```
public class CustomDbContext : ReusableDbContext
{
    public CustomDbContext() 
        : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer＜CustomDbContext＞(new 
MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion＜CustomDbContext, CustomMigrationsConfiguration＞());
    }

    public DbSet＜CustomTable＞ CustomTables{ get; set; }
}

public class CustomMigrationsConfiguration : ReusableMigrationsConfiguration＜CustomDbContext＞
{
    public CustomMigrationsConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(CustomDbContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);



        //CustomMigrationsConfiguration Seed Logic
        // this Seed method is called and OK
    }
}
```

after running the project:

- ReusableTable and CustomTable are created;
- Seed Method of CustomMigrationsConfiguration is called and OK;
- Seed Method of ReusableMigrationsConfiguration is called and OK too.

all things seem to be fine by now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomDbContext : **ReusableDbContext**
{
    public CustomDbContext() 
        : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer＜CustomDbContext＞(new 
MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion＜CustomDbContext, CustomMigrationsConfiguration＞());
    }

    public DbSet＜CustomTable＞ CustomTables{ get; set; }
}
```

Do this it will work

```
public class CustomMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration＜CustomDbContext＞
{
    public ReusableMigrationsConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(CustomDbContext context)
    {
        //CustomMigrationsConfiguration Seed Logic
        // this Seed method is called, no problem here
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eranga @ SONOFGOD I just can't see any difference here, Please notice that class CustomDbContext extends from ReusableDbContext, not DbContext.

Comment: What i intend to do is trying to reuse the Logic of the ReusableDbContext(code first approach of creating common tables) and the ReusableMigrationsConfiguration(the Seed Logic for creating views, stored procedures, etc.), maybe put them in a separated project. In the CustomDbContext you can define your own Tables... By extending from ReusableDbContext, you can save the work to creating those common tables and other common database objects. My problem is that the Seed method of the ReusableMigrationsConfiguration is never called, so that the views, Stored Procedures...can not be created.